# Boy fooled a newspaper-boy to tell the other villagers of a marriage

Tags: identification-request

I was once solving a test passage on Khan Academy last year. It contained a story of a boy who fooled a newspaper-boy to tell all the other residents of a village that a man was marrying a woman. It was an excerpt from a novel that was so very hilarious. What novel is this from?

Comment: Welcome to Literature! What test did you read this passage in? Could you provide us with a year, or even a decade, at least? See the [identification-request wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) for more useful kinds of information.

Comment: it was a khan academy sat reading practice (literature); i saw that last year..however the text was of 19th century something

Comment: Thank you for this update. Please [edit] details into the question directly instead of leaving them in comments, and be as specific as possible.

Comment: Fooling the residents of a village with a fake news story reminds me of Kipling's comic short story "The Village That Voted the Earth Was Flat" (http://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/rg_villagevoted1.htm)